# C++ - 'Not a class or namespace' when try to use global in class

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces, global-variables, c++17

I have a namespace `Global` with a constant static variable before my main function:

```
#include "RaGaCCMainView.h"
#include <QApplication>

namespace Global {
    const static bool isLittleEndian = [](){
        union {
            uint32_t i;
            char c[4];
        } bint = {0x01020304};

        return bint.c[0] == 1;
    }();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    RaGaCCMainView w;
    w.setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Now inside `RaGaCCMainView.h` i want to declare the variable as an extern one:

```
extern const static bool Global::isLittleEndian;
```

This is where i get the corresponding error:

> `C2653: 'Global': is not a class or namespace name`

I just want to use the global variable inside the `RaGaCCMainView.cpp`:

```
void RaGaCCMainView::someFunction()
{
    ...

    if(Global::isLittleEndian) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This seems like a stupid problem but the only answers i could weren't helpful or didn't work. I (obviously) want to declare and define `Global::isLittleEndian` once and just use it in any class I want in this case `RaGaCCMainView`.

### How can make `RaGaCCMainView` knowing that `Global::isLittleEndian` exists and which value it has?

Comment: `namspace Global { extern const static bool isLittleEndian; }`?

Comment: @NathanOliver `error: C2159: more than one storage class specified`

Comment: `static` does not make sense here

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel and do not use http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_LITTLE_ENDIAN ?

Comment: @AdrianW Because the ape wasn't aware of the _wheel_ yet... :). Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a `Endianness.h` file which defines the preprocessor macro `IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN`:

```
#ifndef ENDIANNESS_H
#define ENDIANNESS_H

#include <QtGlobal>

#if Q_BYTE_ORDER == Q_LITTLE_ENDIAN
    #define IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN 1
#else
    #define IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN 0
#endif

#endif // ENDIANNESS_H
```

I include this one in the class `RaGaCCMainView` and use the macro `IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN`.